# Making an image of all the frames of a video with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am currently trying to take a video `input.mp4` and turn it into a image of every frame at 30 frames per second of the entire video.  I have this command that almost works as it makes a image of the entire video but final part

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "select='lt(n,3696)',scale=320:-1,tile=20x100" -frames:v 1 -y a.jpg
```

In order to find the total frames of the video I used this command

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -count_packets -show_entries stream=nb_read_packets -of csv=p=0 input.mp4
```

Which outputs `3696` and the image outputs mostly all of it but the final parts are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The max grid size you have set for the `tile` filter is `20x100`, which means only a maximum of 2000 frames could fit in it, cutting out the last 1696.

A more appropriate grid size could be `28x132`, which should be able to fit the entire video as there will be exactly 3696 cells.

Changing that part of your video filter to `tile=28x132` should therefore show all the frames.